# Does anyone know of an R code to calculate Palmer Drought Severity Index (PDSI)?

Tags: r, indices

Palmer drought severity index is one of the most popular moisture/drought indices around. 
There is a package in R called a SPEI that allows calculation of two other popular drought indices (Standardised precipitation index and Standardised precipitation and evapotranspiration Index ). I think there should be some package to calculate other moisture indices and particularly PDSI but i have been unable to find one myself.

Comment: you might try this on the `r-sig-ecology@r-project.org` mailing list (make sure to mention that you're cross-posting). `library(sos); findFn("drought"); findFn("drought Palmer")` gets 28 hits for the first query, none (oh  well) for the second

Comment: PS: looking at http://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/abs/10.1175/1520-0450%281984%29023%3C1100%3ATPDSIL%3E2.0.CO%3B2 quickly, I understand why no-one has tried to implement it in R.  Looks like a pain.  I wonder how many independent implementations of the algorithm there are ... ?

Comment: I personally knew two implementations an old one in FORTRAN and a new one in C++ that is provided by national drought mitigation center on its website

Comment: If either of them is freely available or (preferably) FOSS, it might not be too hard to make a minimal wrapper for the C++/FORTRAN code that could then be used in R. (A quick google didn't find the code: I got as far as http://drought.unl.edu/MonitoringTools/DownloadableSPIProgram.aspx but didn't see anything for Palmer)

Comment: If you download the compressed file from here it contains a .exe file as well as C++ source code. I believe it is in the public domain as it is a available freely for download and is maintained by a university and Govt funds http://greenleaf.unl.edu/downloads/

Comment: How badly do you want this, and how thoroughly integrated with R do you want it? (Feel free to take this off-SO, to e-mail.)

Comment: pages 18-20 of Liu Sun's thesis seems to provide some relevant formulae: http://cemml.carleton.ca/davidson/publications/2009/Msc%20Thesis_Liu%20Sun.pdf

Comment: TY...i have a code in C++, i was curious whether anyone is working on it in R...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like we can thank Christian Zang for finally solving the problem: https://github.com/cszang/pdsi

**Edit from 2018**: This answer was just accepted so I have decided to [fork the above-linked repo to my github](https://github.com/HFBrowning/pdsi) to guard against future link rot. It will stay there indefinitely.

Answer (score 4):

This is the link for .exe file / C++ code that achieves the same.

It contains a manual that describes the input/ output file formats.

I hope that someones skilled enough can write a wrapper for this

http://greenleaf.unl.edu/downloads/

Comment: Well, has anyone gotten around to doing this????

Answer (score 2):

A tool has been created for MatLab:

Jacobi, J., D. Perrone, L. L. Duncan, and G. Hornberger (2013), A tool for calculating the Palmer drought indices, Water Resour. Res., 49, doi:[10.1002/wrcr.20342](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/wrcr.20342/abstract).

Answer (score 2):

Now library `scPDSI` is available in R for calculation of Palmer Drought Severity Index.

**Update**

The package has been removed from the CRAN repository. But you can use the following code to install the latest archived version

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/scPDSI/scPDSI_0.1.3.tar.gz", 
                 repo=NULL, type="source")
```